# How do I mod Baldur's Gate 1 (GOG edition) with the widescreen mod?

Tags: mods, baldurs-gate

I recently purchased Baldur's Gate 1 from GOG.com and would like to install the widescreen mod. I've looked all over the internet and can not find a decent tutorial on how to do it.

Has anyone out there done this before and if so, how do I do it?

I downloaded the widescreen mod and ran the script (on Windows XP) and was given a windows DOS screen with the error:

```
ERROR: Unable to find DIALOG.TLK in: dialog.tlk

Please run this program in your Infinity Engine game directory. 

FATAL ERROR: Failure("Unable to find DIALOG.TLK")

Please ENTER to exit.
```

I also placed the script in the `C:\Program Files\Black Isle\BGII` directory where the dialog.tlk file is and got the exact same error.

Anyone able to do this successfully? I am running Windows XP and using GOG's version of Baldur's Gate 1.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You're mentioning a Baldur's Gate II path, but you are asking about Baldur's Gate I, is that path really correct?

Comment: Yeah, I just solved the dang thing. It was running the script in my BG2 directory, even though I placed it in the BG1 directory. I had to manually search for my BG1 directory and click install for it to work. I just wasn't paying attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I encountered was that I *placed* the script in the right directory, but I didn't *run* the script in the right directory. The mod I was using was the widescreen mod made by http://www.gibberlings3.net/

Basically when you run the mod it asks you what directory you would like to run the script. Because I already had Baldur's Gate 2 installed, it automatically selected that directory, and because I saw that it was in a directory labeled "Baldur's Gate", I didn't even think to check if it was the right game. I assumed it was the first one. So if you already have Baldur's Gate 2 installed, it will run the script there by default. Right before you click install make sure you are in the correct directory for the script to be run in. That is exactly what the above error is telling the user to do.

Comment: As well, I've found out that when installing the widescreen mod that the Baldur's Gate GUI looks a bit off when place (it doesn't cover the necessary area that it should cover and leaves a big black area in the screen. To remedy this, you need to download the GUI Mod from here: http://athkatla.cob-bg.pl/viewtopic.php?t=3257

Comment: Extract the zipped file in your Baldur's Gate 1 directory and run the installer. It will ask you a series of questions (much like the widescreen mod) but a word of warning. It only supports these resolutions: 1024x600, 1024x768, 1280x768, 1280x800. If you installed the widescreen mod at a higher resolution you will need to uninstall Baldur's Gate and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you also own Baldur's Gate II, you could alternatively use [Baldur's Gate Trilogy](http://www.shsforums.net/index.php?app=downloads&showfile=54&s=bf05cfd9a5d1cb652f5f0dc39513de7c), which allows you to play Baldur's Gate I using the engine of the second part. I vaguely remember that the engine of Baldur's gate II is supposed to have fewer problems with widescreen settings.