# How do I change the resolution of Baldur’s Gate 1?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, baldurs-gate

I have installed *Baldur's Gate 1* (CD), the original, first version, on a Windows 10 computer, and I wanted to play it again.

How can I change the resolution because it's impossible to play with the current one? I found the Widescreen Mod, but it doesn't work with my version. I know I can buy the game on Epic or Steam, but I want to play it offline.

I checked this post too: [How do I mod Baldur's Gate 1 (GOG edition) with the widescreen mod?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/how-do-i-mod-baldurs-gate-1-gog-edition-with-the-widescreen-mod)

Is there any way to achieve this without purchasing the Enhanced Edition or *Baldur's Gate 2*?

**Update:**

After I visited various websites and forums, I believe that changing the resolution in the very first version is almost impossible.

**The game always starts in the default resolution of 640x480, with two thick bars on the right and left sides.**

[image]

So far, I have tried the following methods but don't fix:

1. Widescreen Mod from *The Gibberlings Three*

> The Widescreen Mod allows Planescape:Torment, Baldur's Gate: Tales of the sword Coast, Baldur's Gate II: Shadows of Amn, Baldur's Gate II: Throne of Bhaal, Icewind Dale: Heart of Winter and Icewind Dale II to be played at previously unsupported resolutions, like those of widescreen monitors.

2. Change Variables in `Baldur.ini`(with different values, together and alone)

```
Full Screen=1
Width=1366
height=768
Display Width=1366
Display Height=1366
Graphics Width=1280
Graphics Height=740
```

From this Variables/Values only `Full Screen=1` or `0` works

3. I tried manipulating the `Baldur.exe`  or `BGMain.exe` file with a hex editor, `HxD`, but I couldn't find the corresponding values.
4. I tried the `Infinity Cracker`, but it didn't work either.
5. I tried the tool `DXWnd`(*Window hooker to run fullscreen programs in window*), but it also didn't work.
6. Changing the resolution directly in the system itself, as suggested in the **comments**, also doesn't work

> If the game window is simply too small on your monitor it might be easier to just reduce the resolution on your monitor which can be adjusted....

The only thing I haven't tried yet would be starting a virtual machine with Windows and see if there's any difference when trying to resize the window. I'll also check if the same can be done with Wine on a GNU/Linux system.

**If anyone has any other tips or a solution, perhaps involving the manipulation of the `.exe` file, Or how to get rid of the two bars on the right and left sides, that I can try, otherwise, I'm out of ideas.**

Comment: Why is it impossible to play with the current resolution? If the game window is simply too small on your monitor it might be easier to just reduce the resolution on your monitor which can be adjusted in the windows options.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case but it happens to other games, they're designed only for 4:3 resolutions so there's nothing to do.

Comment: Not a solution or tips, but gog offers enhanced edition which supports 16:9 res(plus [it has access to original edition](https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/9003415445405-Baldur-s-Gate-The-Original-Saga-how-to-access-the-classic-version?product=gog) if you'd prefer; I'd imagine that's the version that is supported by widescreen mod), and is able to play offline (since it's DRM free). If there's no way to achieve your goal, then it'd be your last resort, I guess.

Comment: Try adding 640x480 as a custom screen resolution in your video driver setup.

Answer (score 1):

Very possible to change it, the easiest is perhaps through right click on the Baldur.exe file for Properties, and select the Compatibility tab:
[image: Baldur Properties]

Check the `Run in 640 X 480` box, and launch. This also avoids [An Assertion failed in D:\Dev\chitin\ChVideo.cpp](https://www.gog.com/forum/baldurs_gate_series/baldurs_gate_crash_on_launch) error.

Alternatively, if the monitor supports resolution ratios of 4:3 or even 5:4, it'll work using a program like [PrgLnch](https://github.com/lmstearn/PrgLnch/wiki). Drag Baldur into the config from an explorer window, select the resolution, and run.
The game itself will always render 640X480 though.

**Edit:**
Further research has (given the above is all fine and dandy), revealed that the DirectPlay routines called in BGMain.exe and BGMAIN2.exe actually **do** change the resolution, regardless of what they are set initially.
[SetDisplayMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddraw/nf-ddraw-idirectdraw7-setdisplaymode) is successfully invoked through DirectDraw by mods like [WideScreen](https://gibberlings3.github.io/Documentation/readmes/readme-widescreen.html), given mod installation requirements are met. So far, so good with changing the resolution, the sprites and many other items will not automatically upscale as you well know (related discussion [here](https://forums.beamdog.com/discussion/73868/upscaling-infinity-engine-maps-with-ai).) If playing full screen, many Widescreen users advise going no more than a screen width of 1280, for example.

For original BG1/2 (GOG) installs with Widescreen, look for a GUI replacement like [this](https://www.nexusmods.com/baldursgate/mods/40) that can fix unscaled menu bars and their malcontents. Recommended widescreen resolutions for that:

```
800x480, 800x600, 1024x600, 1024x768, 1280x768, 1280x800
```

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is hoping for something larger than 640 x 480, since that is the native resolution the game runs on.

Comment: @Joachim: [Textures](https://www.reddit.com/r/baldursgate/comments/1007hbc/would_it_be_prohibitively_expensive_to_redo_bg_1/)? Hope of all hope that someone from Bioware ever remembers what happened to the original game creation files.

Comment: Yes, I hope so too, but hat has nothing to do with the screen resolution :)

Comment: @Joachim: Ran it under 1280 X 1024, unable to detect any visible change in rendering. Any success your end?